# IProcessHostPreloadClient.Preload feature with application pool in classic mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, autostart, warm-up

I am trying to add [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/09/15/auto-start-asp-net-applications-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx) feature to my project. It is work for my test web application on application pool in integrated mode. But when I am trying to change application pool mode from Integrated to Classic, it seems Preload method not called after that. Is somebody facing with the same problem? Or this feature not working in classic mode?

Thanks, 
Maksim